# Core-Data with API consumption

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, design-patterns, core-data

I have an application which calls webservice in background thread and at the same time it displays data by fetching data from core-data in main-thread.

I am sure this approach has lots of loop-holes

I am looking for best approach to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use RestKit framework. It do all you needed.